# NVIDIA GeForce 9200 Ubuntu 13.10 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

What is the best driver to use with this GPU? Ubuntu is running fine with the internal driver, but is there a better one available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Nvidia proprietary drivers, open a terminal and use:-

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the geforce website, you can perform a manual search to get the latest proprietary driver available for your GPU.

http://www.geforce.com/drivers

There, a search for the geforce 9M series, Linux 64 bits, english and recommended (not beta) gives you the 331.38